# How to play .wav file attached to (Voice over IP) voice-mail files in Android?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, voip, soundpool, audiotrack

need to play .wav file (attached to a voicemail) in a device with Android 4.3.1 (API 18) installed.

I am aware that there are some app like 'remote wav' that are able to play .wav file however I need to make this inbuilt feature for my app.

any help will be really appreciated; perhaps what I am looking for is to find out if there is a library to play .wav via default android Mediaplayer class or even first to convert it to any other format then play it ...

thanks for time in advance

I tried this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    SoundPool mPlayer;
    int mSoundId ;
    Button play1;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mPlayer = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        mSoundId = mPlayer.load(this, R.raw.s2, 1);
        Button play1 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay1);
        play1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mPlayer.play(mSoundId, 0.99f, 0.99f, 0, 0, 1f);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

but does not work, I got

```
11-26 16:31:14.019 7971-7971 W/SoundPool:   sample 1 not READY
```

I think this type of wav (attached to voicemails) is different type and can not be handle by Mediaplayer/SoundPool.
see https://www.onsip.com/blog/free-way-to-listen-to-wav-files-on-your-android-device 
I can attach the file (sample.wav) so you can try if you want.

---

edited: ------------------------
as Philip Sander suggested I tried [Soundpool sample not ready](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5202510/5235263)  but none of the replied answers worked for me (no sound output)

---

edited:--------------------------
I applied AudioTrack approach explained [Using AudioTrack in Android to play a WAV file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3925030/5235263) but the result was 
some statics noises (white noises only for few seconds)
then I applied [Android AudioTrack playing .wav file, getting only white noise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7372813/5235263) , this asn this to fix the statics noise, however no luck, I am running out of idea and really appreciate new ones, this is a link to a sample wav file [here](http://www.clayloomis.com/Sounds/simp276f.wav)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883883/playing-short-wav-files-android 10 seconds googling...

Comment: I added more info Philipp. ;)

Comment: and what have you tried to make it work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202510/soundpool-sample-not-ready

Comment: thanks for reply , I will give it a go and let you know.  TA

Comment: I will ignore this question from nowon because you show 0 effort to solve oyur own problems.

Comment: well thanks for help anyway, not happy with your comment though, how did you conclude I put zero effort, the first link you provided I tried myself before posting this, in fact I spend couple of hours into this I wish you were more patient considering my ranking you should have a rough idea that I am new in development!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96351/discussion-between-bastami1982-and-philipp-sander).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a library to play `.wav` files, the `android.media.MediaPlayer` can play WAV files normally the way other formats are played.

```
MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.file_name);
    /*Then to start the player*/
player.start();
```

Comment: Hi Colns, that was my first attempt but in my surprise I got this :  (.NullPointerException)           
11-26 16:37:14.969 20287-20287 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-26 16:37:14.969 20287-20287 E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-26 16:37:14.969 20287-20287 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.bastamib.wavplayer.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:38)