# how to play 32 bit float wav file in Android 4.3.1 (wav file attached as a voice mail in VOIP)?

Tags: android, audio, wav, voip, voicemail

This type of wav file (32bit float 8000hz mono) which is attached to voicemails, is different type and can not be handle by Mediaplayer/SoundPool. see [this link](https://www.onsip.com/blog/free-way-to-listen-to-wav-files-on-your-android-device)  here is a [link](http://www.clayloomis.com/Sounds/simp276f.wav) to a similar sample.wav file so you can try it yourself if you want.(it is wav 32 bit float 11025hz mono)

---

my first attempt was to play it via mediaPlayer but it throw a NullPointerException: here is log cat :

```
 - 11-26 16:37:14.969 20287-20287 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:main
 - 11-26 16:37:14.969 20287-20287 E/AndroidRuntime:
   java.lang.NullPointerException 
 - 11-26 16:37:14.969 20287-20287 E/AndroidRuntime: at   
   com.example.bastamib.wavplayer.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:38)
```

---

Then I used SoundPool :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    SoundPool mPlayer;
    int mSoundId ;
    Button play1;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mPlayer = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        mSoundId = mPlayer.load(this, R.raw.s2, 1);
        Button play1 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay1);
        play1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mPlayer.play(mSoundId, 0.99f, 0.99f, 0, 0, 1f);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

but did not work, I got

```
11-26 16:31:14.019 7971-7971 W/SoundPool:   sample 1 not READY
```

---

to fix

> sample 1 not READY

I tried [Soundpool sample not ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202510/soundpool-sample-not-ready) but none of the replied answers including the selected answer worked for me (basically no sound output)

---

Then I moved to AudioTrack solution: 
explained here [Using AudioTrack in Android to play a WAV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925030/using-audiotrack-in-android-to-play-a-wav-file)

result was some static noises ! not interesting at all ! pifff

---

to fix that I applied [Android AudioTrack playing .wav file, getting only white noise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372813/android-audiotrack-playing-wav-file-getting-only-white-noise)
but no luck applied all answers there and still getting statics noises.

and Here I am stuck ! any help will be appreciated.

a side note : I am aware that there are some app like 'remote wav' that are able to play VOIP .wav file however I need to make this inbuilt feature for my app.